# How to properly control the google analytics cookie from javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

Currently I have set up the cookie prompt to override `document.cookie` set method, so that it stores non-required cookies and waits for user input (which cookies the user allows to use in the web page) to decide about other cookies.

Code looks something like this:

```
const originalSetter = document.__lookupSetter__('cookie');

function newSetter(cookie) {
    if (isRequired(cookie)) {
        originalSetter(cookie);
    } 
    else {
        //store the cookie and decide later.
    }
}
document.__defineSetter__('cookie', newSetter);
```

Since the google analytics cookie is not a required one (at least in my page), is this the correct approach or is there another way to do this?

Comment: [`__lookupSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupSetter__) is deprecated, so I would say that it is not the way going forward. Don't know anything about Google Analytics though.